# Onclick 1st Div goes last in the list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, zk

I create collapsible tab and I want some changes is there if once click on 1st tab this will be goes last in the collapsible list and same for the other tab also. (If having 4 tab and click on 1st tab in the list 1st is goes last 2 3 4 **1**)

Thanks in advances...

Comment: What you have tried so far

Comment: If you read this question would you be able to tell what it was about ?

Comment: post your code on fiddle it gives us idea what you are looking for

Comment: English Please? Maybe some code examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div>div 1</div>
<div>div 2</div>
<div>div 3</div>
<div>div 4</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$('.wrapper').find('div').on('click', function(){
    $(this).appendTo( $(this).parent() )
})
```

Working Code: http://jsfiddle.net/P7tap/